# Applying for a mathematics PhD in the US after getting a BSc degree from Imperial

Tags: phd, application, united-states, united-kingdom, bachelor

This summer I finished my BSc maths degree at Imperial College London and ranked around top 5% of the class.

I was considering the idea of applying to some US universities like Stanford, Harvard, etc., but they don't do master's applications, just straight up PhD ones for mathematics. I quite like the idea of doing a PhD, so it is not a big problem for me, but I was wondering about my chances here, coming off a BSc and applying straight to a PhD sounds like a big reach.

Has anybody had similar experiences and know if it's even worth trying?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Go for it. But bear in mind that competition for math PhD at places like Harvard and Stanford is so *extremely* fierce it is difficult to really grasp... Talk to your professors at Imperial and see whether anyone has any contacts and/or suggestions. Your letters need to be extremely strong.

Answer (score 11):

Most US students enter doctoral studies after "only" a bachelors degree. It isn't a reach at all. But expect there to be coursework and exams. The coursework is something like what you would get in a masters, but is intended primarily to prepare you for the qualifying examinations. Serious dissertation research often starts after you've done a couple of years of other things. But you aren't likely to finish in three years from where you are now. Expect something like twice that.